# Regex for IPV4 but also to allow a unique word

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to see if I can validate an ASP.Net textbox that allows a user to enter in an IPV4 address, but if there is not a particular IPv4 address to enter in the word Any.

Now my regex works for IPV4, but I am unsure how I can extend it to include the word Any.

Can anyone help me, please - \b(?:\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}\b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add alternation:

```
\b(?:(?:\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}|Any)\b
```